# can i emulate windows ce 6 in pc without visual studio 2005

Tags: windows-ce, emulation

I've already built windows ce 6.0 and run it in windows ce emulator.
but I want to run this without visual studio 2005.
I found emulator for windows ce 5.0, but **I couldn't find emulator for windows ce 6.0.**

somebody help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying you have created a CE image that does boot up in the Device Emulator?  If that's the case, then you probably just need to install the [stand-alone Device Emulator v3 bits](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A6F6ADAF-12E3-4B2F-A394-356E2C2FB114&displaylang=en) (and your image) on the target PC.